# How to remove all child div element except first div using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some child div element, which is created dynamically. I want to remove all the div element of the parent, except the first child.

Here is my code what I tried

```js
function someFunction(obj, abc) {
  if ($(obj).children().hasClass("glyphicon-plus")) {
    //There is some code
  } else {
    var classname = abc;
    var mergeFolderName = classname.split(" ");

    var fullClassName = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < mergeFolderName.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        fullClassName = fullClassName + "-" + mergeFolderName[i];
      } else {
        fullClassName = 'parent-folder-' + mergeFolderName[i];
      }
    }
    alert("After merge = " + fullClassName); //parent-folder-Great-Plains

    if ($(obj).parent().hasClass(fullClassName)) {

      var count = $("." + fullClassName).children().length;
      alert("child div length = " + count); //length = 3


      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        alert("class NO=" + i + "    Name = " + $("." + fullClassName).children('div:eq(' + i + ')').attr("class"));
        if (i > 0) { //remove 2 and 3
          $("." + fullClassName).children('div:eq(' + i + ')').remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-folder-Great-Plains">

  <div class="MainFolder Great Plains folder-icon" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder1')" style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> Folder1
  </div>
  <div class="MainFolder folder-icon Accounts" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder2')" style="padding-left:20px;">Folder2</div>
  <div class="MainFolder folder-icon Purchase" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder3')" style="padding-left:20px;">Folder3</div>
</div>
```

**Note**

> User will click on Folder1, then it has to remove folder2 and folder3.

My problem is when the user clicks on `Folder1`, it removes `folder2`, but not `folder3`

**UPDATE**

> I don't want to use like `abc = 'Folder1'`, because it will not be the same folder name. I want to go to parent folder of `Folder1`, then I want to remove all the subdiv of parent,except first div

Comment: Noting is being removed for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(obj)                     //Select the object
   .parent()               //Select the parent of the object
   .children()             //Select all the children of the parent
   .not(':first-child')    //Unselect the first child
   .remove();              //Remove
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
function someFunction(obj, abc) {
  $(obj).parent().children().not(':first-child').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-folder-Great-Plains">
  <div class="MainFolder Great Plains folder-icon" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder1')" style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> Folder1
  </div>
  <div class="MainFolder folder-icon Accounts" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder2')" style="padding-left:20px;">Folder2</div>
  <div class="MainFolder folder-icon Purchase" onclick="someFunction(this,'Folder3')" style="padding-left:20px;">Folder3</div>
</div>
```

Doc: [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: I don't want to use like `abc = 'Folder1'`, because it will not be the same folder name. I want to go to parent folder of `Folder1`, then I want to remove all the subdiv of parent,except first div